# Add a column from subquery to the SELECT of main query without applying filteres from WHERE in main query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a help with following problem:

So I have a table TABLE1 with columns Date, Name, STAT1, STAT2, PROBLEM1

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT Date, Name, sum(STAT1), sum(STAT2)
FROM TABLE1
WHERE PROBLEM1 <> 0 
GROUP BY Date, Name
```

The result of this query is what I want but I also need to add 2 columns: TOTALCOUNT which is basically the number of rows for each group without applying the filter (PROBLEM1 <> 0 ) and COUNTERRORS which is count for each group where PROBLEM1 = 0.

So to give you further example. For a Date A, and Name B I have 1000 rows. 300 of them have PROBLEM1 = 0.
I run the first query I mentioned above and it calculates my sum(STAT1), sum(STAT2) based on 700 rows because of the filter WHERE PROBLEM1 <> 0. And I need to find a way to add two columns to the result so in the end my table would look like:

```
DATE NAME sum(STAT1)  sum(STAT2) TOTALCOUNT COUNTERRORS
A     B       50          3.5      1000        300
```

Is it possible to do? I was trying using subqueries but without a success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do *conditional* aggregation :

```
SELECT Date, Name, 
       sum(case when PROBLEM1 <> 0  then stat1 else 0 end) as stat1, 
       sum(case when PROBLEM1 <> 0  then stat2 else 0 end) as stat2, 
       count(*) as TOTALCOUNT,
       sum(PROBLEM1 = 0) as COUNTERRORS 
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY Date, Name;
```

Comment: Use `NULLIF()` instead of the `CASE`'s: `SUM(NULLIF(Problem1, 0)) AS Stat1`... Also `Counterrors` should be `COUNT()` not `SUM()`...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto. . . `MySQL`  has shorthand for conditional aggregation to count rows based on condition.  So,  `sum(PROBLEM1 = 0)` will produce count whereas `problem1 = 1` founds.

Comment: Yes, my bad: The logical value of TRUE is 1, and FALSE is 0 in MySQL...